# How to Use http.StreamedRequest for audio Streaming Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, http, stream, just-audio

I am working on an audio streaming App. My goal is to write the buffer into a file and read the audio from the file.

Here is my problem : when i am doing a get request to the server , it wait to get all the buffers from the song before writing it into the file.

I would like to write the buffer into the file as soon as they are send to the response body.

I thought about using http.StreamedRequest but i dont really know how to use it.

Here is my current code :

```
  //Function getting the buffers of the songs
   getBeat(String type) async {
    print("Entering Get Beat");
    lastBeatType = type;

    AudioManager _audioManager = AudioManager(lastBeatType: type);


    final response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse("http://localhost:5000/beat?type=$type"));

    
  
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final songdata = jsonDecode(response.body);
      
      final buffer = await http.get(Uri.parse("http://localhost:5000/audiovideoId=${songdata["id"]}"));
      writeBuffer(buffer.bodyBytes);
       String path = await _localPath;
      _audioPlayer.setFilePath("$path/currentSong.mp3");
    }
   }
```

Anyhelp would be appreciate !

Comment: I believe you need sockets or any other continuous data sharing technology

Comment: Thank you for your answer , I am going to try to implement webSocket with flutter and ill post my code if that worked.

Comment: @Hamidou did you get this working?